# How to add lifetime argument to closure not returning a reference

Tags: rust, closures, lifetime

Assume you have a function returning a closure which works on a reference.
Sure, the object behind the reference must life at least as long as the closure is called.

Here a very simple example, which demonstrates the problem.

```rust
fn get_cloned<'a>(obj: &'a MyStruct) -> impl Fn() -> MyStruct {
    || {obj.clone()}
}
```

The compiler states that the returned closure has lifetime *static*:

> cannot infer an appropriate lifetime
>   ...but this borrow...rustc
>   main.rs(60, 56): this return type evaluates to the `'static` lifetime...
>   main.rs(61, 5): ...but this borrow...

How can I tell the compiler that I only use the result of the function (the closure) as long as the reference is valid?

Thanks!

**[Edit]**

Do you need a dummy struct which holds the reference as well as the closure?

```rust
struct Dummy<'a>{
  reference: &'a MyStruct,
  closure: Fn() -> MyStruct
}
```

?

Assume that cloning is very costly and the closure might never be called. -> lazy evaluation is a must.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler tells you what to do:

```
error: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime
 --> src/lib.rs:2:9
  |
1 | fn get_cloned<'a>(obj: &'a MyStruct) -> impl Fn() -> MyStruct {
  |                                         --------------------- this return type evaluates to the `'static` lifetime...
2 |         || {obj.clone()}
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ...but this borrow...
  |
note: ...can't outlive the lifetime 'a as defined on the function body at 1:15
 --> src/lib.rs:1:15
  |
1 | fn get_cloned<'a>(obj: &'a MyStruct) -> impl Fn() -> MyStruct {
  |               ^^
help: you can add a constraint to the return type to make it last less than `'static` and match the lifetime 'a as defined on the function body at 1:15
  |
1 | fn get_cloned<'a>(obj: &'a MyStruct) -> impl Fn() -> MyStruct + 'a {
  |                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You need to add `+ 'a` on the return type. The compiler will then tell you you're missing `move`, but after fixing that, [your code works](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7bf207fbeec3895be2fe0d0295f901b4):

```
fn get_cloned<'a>(obj: &'a MyStruct) -> impl Fn() -> MyStruct + 'a {
    || {obj.clone()}
}
```